# Do I need to wait for another review when my app is already approvedand [Pending developer release] and I want to test it in [BetaTesting]?

Tags: app-store-connect, beta-testing

I need to know if I have to wait for another review proccess after I already did it and my app is now in Pending Developer Release.

The point is I need to keep it in [PDRelease] mode until my testers say everything is ok, publish it.

But it has no sense if the app is approved and waiting "manual release" and then I need to resend it to another review or better called: "Beta testing review".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is correct, they are two separate workflows... If you had submitted the build to be approved for public beta testing and submitted it to the store at the same time you would be in a different place. Whether or not behind the scene it checks the work flow value to see if its pending release and short circuits the review is completely opaque as far as I know.